Indexes of nonhyperbolic equilibrium points in planar vector fields
There is a well-known theorem in dynamical systems stating that if $\gamma$ is a "sufficiently nice" closed curve (continuous, piecewise smooth, nonconstant function from $[a,b]$, say $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$) enclosing precisely one hyperbolic equilibrium point with winding number 1 around that point in $\mathbb R^2$, then its index with respect to the vector field is:

-1 if the equilibrium is a saddle and
1 if the equilibrium is a sink or source.

Let $F\in C^1(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$ and system (A) be given by $(\dot{x},\dot{y})=F(x,y)$.
Is there any general statement that can be made if the equilibrium is nonhyperbolic? Or can the the index then only be determined by computing $\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{F_1dF_2-F_2dF_1}{F_1^2+F_2^2}$, which evaluates to the horrible expression $\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_\Omega\left[\frac{f_x+g_x}{f^2+g^2}+2\frac{(f+g)(f_x+g_x)}{(f^2+g^2)^2}\right]dfdg$ for $(f,g)=F=(F_1,F_2)$ using Green's theorem and even then requires finding local inverses of $F_1,F_2$ and taking the determinant of their Jacobian to bring the integral to the $dxdy$ form, which would also morph the shape of $\Omega$. Is there an easier way or am I misinterpreting something?
